# Can I specify specific light frequencies to sample on an Android phone?

Tags: android, android-camera, frequency, light, infrared

I would like to be able to select light frequencies to display on my Android. Unrequired frequencies would be displayed as black; the required frequency as white. Thus the output would be monochrome.

This would allow searching by colour, for example 400 nanometres. It would permit digging around in the infrared for particular frequencies, not just a ballpark infrared value.

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3.

**LATER**

For those interested in Android Spectroscopy: 
[Spectral Workbench](http://publiclab.org/notes/warren/6-12-2012/mobile-android-version-spectral-workbench) and [LearnLight](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.flappit.learnlight&hl=en), ["Software turns every camera phone into a spectrometer"](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2010-10/11/camera-phone-spectrometer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use your phone as a spectrometer. I don't think this is possible, because the camera sensor uses 3 filters to get colored images (red, green, blue) so you can only separate this 3 channels and not a single frequency ([more details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor#Color_separation)).